# C# Scope_Identity Issue

Tags: c#, sql, scope-identity, executescalar

Browsed some answers and doesn't appear to be working for me.

I need the ID field of a table to be returned so I can use it in a different part of the program, I've tried using

```
    Convert.ToInt32(sqlComm.ExecuteScalar());
```

But no luck, and same for

```
    Convert.ToInt32(sqlComm.Parameters["ID"].Value);
```

And both return 0, even though the record does get inserted into the table.

I'll dump the code below, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnect = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("up_Insert_Address", sqlConnect))
            {
                sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@AddressID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@AddressLineOne", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = address.AddressLineOne;   

                try
                {
                    sqlComm.Connection.Open();
                    return Convert.ToInt32(sqlComm.ExecuteScalar());
                }

                catch (SqlException)
                {
                }

                finally
                {
                    sqlComm.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

And Stored Procedure:

```
    @AddressID   Bigint OUTPUT,
    @AddressLineOne  NVarChar(40)
    AS
     BEGIN
      BEGIN TRY
      INSERT INTO Address
      (
         AddressLineOne
      )
      VALUES 
      (
         @AddressLineOne
      )

      SET @AddressID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
       DECLARE @Err nvarchar(500)
       SET @Err = ERROR_MESSAGE()
       RAISERROR(@Err, 16, 1)
    END CATCH
   END
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using

```
Convert.ToInt64(sqlComm.Parameters["@AddressID"].Value);
```

after you execute the command using `ExceuteNonQuery`.  For future reference, `ExecuteScalar`  returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query.  You're not returning anything, just setting the value of an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Also you should DEFINITELY not swallow any `SqlException`. Since your command and connection are already in `using` blocks you don't need to add another try/catch/finally.  Change it to to:

```
//try
//{
    sqlComm.Connection.Open();
    sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    return Convert.ToInt64(sqlComm.Parameters["@AddressID"].Value);
    // using Int64 since the SQL type is BigInt
//}

//catch (SqlException)
//{
//}

//finally
//{
//    sqlComm.Connection.Close();
//}
```

Comment: You're welcome - please see my update on removing the `catch` block.

Comment: I would recommend using `long.TryParse()` on the result (`OUTPUT` parameter) as an added measure to prevent an exception being thrown. It should never happen, but maybe if someone later changes the schema, this way existing code would be more fault-tolerant.

Comment: @SiLo - I disagree.  The return value should ALWAYS by a `BigInt`, not a string that needs to be parsed.  Casting should be fine.  If there's an error on casting you WANT that exception.

Comment: @D Stanley - Did you mean to type:  `Convert.ToInt32(sqlComm.Parameters["@AddressID"].Value);` in the first code example and `Convert.ToInt64(sqlComm.Parameters["@AddressID"].Value);` in the second?

Comment: I corrected it after I saw that the parameter is a `BigInt`.  Corrected the first example.

Comment: @DStanley you are correct. I was thinking it returned as a string or object with string formatting. Since it keeps its native type, that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

var addressId = 0L; // long value (64bit)

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("up_Insert_Address", connection))
{
  command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressID", addressId);    
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLineOne", address.AddressLineOne); 

  command.Parameters["@AddressID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

  try
  {
    if(connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
      connection.Open();

    var rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    addressId = Convert.ToInt64(command.Parameters["@AddressID"].Value);
  }
  catch (SqlException)
  {
    // Handle SQL errors here.
  }
}
```